# URL Redirection not working in Android via Intent - (Page Not Found Error)

Tags: android, mobile-browser

I have this code:

```
Button bluehost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bluehost);
bluehost.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.bluehost.com/track/businessplan/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

Technically, this code works to send the person to that url, but for some reason this particular URL goes to a page not found from this code, but renders if you put this url into a browser. But when done from the app it goes to page not found. I am testing with Android Safari browser.

Is it because of the redirect on the URL? And how could I fix this?

I do have this line in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

NOTE:

Internet connection is NOT the problem. This code works for other URLs. It is something strange that is happening with this specific link.

Thanks!

Comment: post the manifest file's code..

Comment: @AvijitKarmakar I updated my original question. Was this permission what you were curious about?

Comment: I will get back to you soon..

Comment: your code is working here..can you post the full code where you have written..

Comment: make sure you have internet connected in device or virtual device check it in web browser of testing device, even you got same situation than post complete code

Comment: @Survivor internet connectivity is not the problem. It is connected to the Internet and is able to surf the web with any other link other than this one I am using now.

Comment: then use `Uri.parse("http://www.bluehost.com/track/businessplan"));`

Comment: @Survivor you mean without the s? I already tried that and that also doesn't work :(

Comment: @Genadinik your code is working properly. i have tested it

Comment: @Genadinik have you tried with other browser?

Comment: It is bug, try to use GoogleChrome

Comment: @Rajesh it works on Chrome and not on Android's default web browser, which MANY people have

Comment: Is there a way I can make it automatically open chrome?

Comment: I never knew Safari for Android existed. Even if it did, how many would use it?

Comment: please install firefox app and run on firefox app because default Browser not support and firefox support it. i am not know why but try it.

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Comment: your code will work properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in my answer below and the corresponding redirect worked for me.

On my Xperia Z Ultra, it looks like this:
[image]

According to the official Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation), it should also work on previous api level below 19. *I assumed the Chrome documentation mentioned the minimum api level number 19 because it was specifically targeting web developers that wanted to use its HTML5 functionality.*

That being said, this solution **does not work** with my old Sprint XPRT (Android 2.3.5 - API Level 10) and it **does not work** on an emulated Nexus S (with an old image of KitKat on it). It says **"web page not found"** on both. And when I further tried it on my XPRT using the browser, but entered the url manually, I get the dialog that "A secure connection could not be established". Unfortunately, removing the 's' in https doesn't work either, because it redirects to the secure version, and I still get "A secure connection could not be established".

**Earlier Answer:**

If you follow that Chrome WebView [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted) exactly. You'll get to this part. The emphasis in **bold** is mine.

> **Handling Navigation**
>
> Now try changing the URL you're loading to
>   http://www.html5rocks.com/ and rerun your application. You'll notice
>   something strange.
>
> **If you run the application now with a site that has a redirect like
>   html5rocks.com, your app ends up opening the site in a browser on the
>   device, not in your WebView** -- probably not what you expected. This is
>   because of the way the WebView handles navigation events.
>
> Here's the sequence of events:
>
> 1. The WebView tries to load the original URL from the remote server, and
>      gets a redirect to a new URL.
> 2. The WebView checks if the system can
>      handle a view intent for the URL, if so the system handles the URL
>      navigation, otherwise the WebView will navigate internally (i.e. the
>      user has no browser installed on their device).
> 3. The system picks the
>      user's preferred application for handling an http:// URL scheme --
>      that is, the user's default browser. If you have more than one browser
>      installed, you may see a dialog at this point.

**In other words, if you just stop the tutorial at this point, you'll get the behavior you desire.**

Here is the actual code in case the [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted) to that tutorial stops working:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
       mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.bluehost.com/track/businessplan/");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }     
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">
     tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

         <WebView
         android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Also for anyone else reading this, I am not mentioning the needed INTERNET permission in the manifest because the original person asking already has that part covered.

Comment: @stephen Branczyk wow what an amazing answer - and yes I do need it to run with earlier versions of Android. Could you please explain how I can do that? Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to have both versions of the code run by checking what os the user has? Is there an advantage of having some of the people use the newer way?

Comment: Actually, forget the part about the minimum sdk version. I was rewriting the solution using the official documentation, and I ended up with the same exact code. Also, I was giving you too much code since I was copying the code from the entire tutorial. Obviously, you don't need to write your own custom WebViewClient, because that part removes the very behavior you do want to keep for your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you get Page not found error in Android Safari browser then you can open link in chrome browser which many devices have or give option to user to select browser application which will open link in selected browser.

For opening link into google chrome browser you have to check whether it is installed in device. for that you can use this method to check whether chrome browser is installed or not.

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
     PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
     try {
         pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
         return true;
     } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

packge name of chrome browser is `com.android.chrome`. you have to set this as package name using `browserIntent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");`

For Showing options to user to select application you can create like this:

```
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Select Application");
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Here is your final code:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                  Uri.parse("https://www.bluehost.com/track/businessplan/"));
boolean isChromeInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.android.chrome", YourActivityName.this);
if (isChromeInstalled) {
    browserIntent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}else{
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Select Application");
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

But note that if you give option to select browser application then Safari browser also listed.

or you can also have option of using `Webview`as answered by [Stephan Branczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320111/stephan-branczyk)

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain bugs available with the browsers.

> Support for SPDY and HTTP/2 is limited to certain modern versions of
>   Google Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari, and Internet Explorer browsers.
>   For more detailed information, take a look at http://caniuse.com/spdy
>   for what browsers support SPDY and at http://caniuse.com/http2 for
>   what browsers support HTTP/2.
>
> All browsers only support SPDY and HTTP/2 over a TLS connection.
>   Therefore HTTPS has to be used to leverage SPDY or HTTP/2.

When i try the link in the chrome browser it says, " Web Page not Available ". But when i try the same in opera browser, it opens.

> On Chrome browser it says " ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR ". while i surfing
>   around the internet it says, it is the bug exist in Chrome browser
>   itself. **One of the possible solution is to try the workaround
>   mentioned in this reference** [link](http://appuals.com/best-fix-steps-to-fix-error-err_spdy_protocol_error/)

1. Try to update the browsers available in your mobile to the latest version.
2. The actual site may be down for maintenance.
3. If you installed "Avast App in your mobile", try to add the link
4. SPDY sessions in Chrome can be inspected via the URI: chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SPDY_SESSION%20is:active.
   You might find something like this there:

   SPDY Enabled: true

   Use Alternate Protocol: true

   Force SPDY Always: false

   Force SPDY Over SSL: true

   Next Protocols: http/1.1,spdy/2,spdy/3

If you just set "SPDY Enabled" option to false, the problem would be solved as after that, HTTP will be used for the web communication.

5. Sometimes avast may also causes the problem if you installed avast app in your mobile. Go to Settings > Active Protection > Customize Web Shield > Exclusions > Add "your link here".

Hopefully it may help you.. in some case!!. Sorry for my bad english.

**Source collected from Internet.**

Answer (score 0):

your code is open the url in device browser if the redirection is not working, definitely the problem is not on your code. it may because of the redirection in the website is not working or the browser you are using can not perform this redirection. in your case i guess is the browser your are using can not perform the redirection.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use this
```

Uri uri = Uri.parse( "https://www.bluehost.com/track/businessplan/" );
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), "Choose browser"));